# Are Colossus's good manners and gentlemanly demeanor because he's Russian?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

In the comics, are Colossus's good manners and gentlemanly demeanor because he's Russian?

At least, he seems to be strongly attempted to fit a stereotypical Russian "intelligentsia" - down to disliking bad language.

(I know the bit about being taken by Professor X at a young age, but so were, IIRC, some other, far edgier and less well mannered X-men members).

I'm looking for either explicit reasoning from the comics or WoG.

Comment: Isn't the stereotypical Russian the opposite of that?

Comment: Have you ever been to Russia?

Comment: @JK. - other than having grown up there (like Colossus), no :)

Comment: @RogueJedi - note the "intelligentsia" part. There are two stereotypes, on the opposite ends of the spectrum.

Comment: I think it's more about playing with the "gentle giant" trope, combined with him fitting the "farm boy" stereotype (Colossus grew up on one), much like Clark Kent or (in the X-books) Sam Guthrie are also polite types.  I doubt the writers based it on his being Russian.

Comment: Piotr wasn't that young when he joined up with the X-Men. His personality and manners have been consistent since his first appearance (minus the times where he's had severe personality shifts due to storylines).

Comment: Why not Canadian? I mean, I think there are other similar stereotypes closer to home in American popular culture...

Comment: @thegreatjedi - my first association with Canada is Justin Bieber and hockey. Not quite the stereotypes fitting Colossus. And i'm too foreign to internalize Dudley Do-Right

Comment: Related answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120746/62088).

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To if you reject Dudley, does that mean you are after moose and squirrel?

Answer (score 3):

## Colossus is just a simple farmboy

The only commentary I can find on Colossus's origin is this, from wikipedia:

> Editor Roy Thomas, in charge of reviving the X-Men for Giant-Size X-Men #1 (May 1975), told the creative team to go home and create some characters for the new team. Dave Cockrum recalled:
>
> > I just went home and Colossus was one of the first ones that came to mind. We needed a strong guy for the team, so I drew up a strong guy. The character's armor just kind of fell into place. He was accepted pretty much as-is, except that I had given him bare legs because it seemed only logical that if we're going to show him armored up, the legs should be bare like the arms. But Len Wein didn't like male characters with bare legs. So we decided that his costume would be blue when he wasn't armored up, and that we'd see his legs when he was armored up, due to the unstable molecules of his costume.

Humble Farmboys are a [common trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FarmBoy) (warning - TVTropes link!), and Colossus is no different from Clark Kent in that regard.

My other suspicion that his demeanor is not an intentional reflection of his country of birth, is that when he was created (1975) the US and USSR (later to become Russia) were embroiled in the [Cold War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union%E2%80%93United_States_relations#Cold_War_(1947%E2%80%9391)), so if anything Colossus was meant to play against 'type'.

Some of the inspiration for the farmboy origin could be from Len Wein's attendance at [Farmingdale State College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmingdale_State_College) which has a history of agriculture. His other creator, David Cockrum, is a Vietnam war vet, which could have potentially contributed to his nuanced view of cultures that would have normally been seen as antagonistic at the time of Colossus' creation.

Another thing to note is that one of Len's prior super hero creations is [Red Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_(comics)) (co-created with [Marv Wolfman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marv_Wolfman) and [Bill Draut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Draut)), who is also Russian and resembles Colossus's brother [Mikhail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Rasputin). There is no indication that I could find, that this Russian superhero shows a noteworthy amount of 'good manners' or 'gentlemanly demeanor'.

So it seems the two facts, Colossus's mannerisms and his country of birth would be intentionally connected.